# Popping off to MoreViewController tab from its stacked screens

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I select more tab of app, got to some screen, do one more selection in that screen. So two screens on the stack, and present a modalView there.

Given the above scenaria, I need to traverse user back to `More` tab from, where he has come.
I tried by myself, later referred to some suggestions on internet which didn't solve the problem.

I wrote below code, which is similar to what other people suggested as well.

> [[self.tabBarController moreNavigationController]
>   dismissModalViewController:YES] [[self.tabBarController
>   moreNavigationController] popToRootViewController:YES]

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for a lot of delay in referring to this. I have just test checked this.

Notes:

1. For more tab related, more UINavigationController is used and unless
   we change the navigation flow on more, screen stack can be accessed
   by more UINavigationController.
2. I was able to popToRootView from pushed screen and modelled screen **BY**

> [self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController
>   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
>   [self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController
>   popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];